# What does the "Resistance contacts" SITREP do in Xcom2 War of the Chosen?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

According to the description "Undercover civilians present in this combat zone can be contacted to gain valuable rewards"

What are the rewards? Do I automatically gain all rewards when I complete the mission? Or should I run around and do the bonus first, then focus on the mission?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I completed the mission.

There were three civilians with a circle around them. Approaching each one has rewarded me with ~33 Supplies, for a total of 100 for all three.